# Android sqlite deleting and inserting rows

Tags: android, sqlite

I am having trouble managing my app with a SQLite Database.

Here's how I would like the app to flow and how the SQLite Db should look.

When you launch it the first time it puts three rows of data in based on some starter objects.

Id_ 1  "Bob"
 Id_2   "Bill"
 Id_3   "Steve"

At different points when the app is being used the user can choose to add a new row.

delete (Bob)
Id_1 "Bob"
Id_2 "Bill"
Id_3 "Steve"
Id_4 "Tony"

Also, the user can delete a row based upon the name of the object.

delete(Bob)
Id_1 "Bill"
Id_2 "Steve"
Id_3 "Tony

When I just use an Adapter class to delete the row (or all the rows) and then try to insert a new row, it deletes the row and doesn't the others to fill that gap.  How can I fill that in?

Do I need to find that row, then update that row with the values from the next row and repeat that until I have moved them all down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you made changes to the DB for data in an active cursor, simply use the requery method and your list will refresh along with the cursor.

```
yourCursor.requery();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I see that requery has been deprecated so this looks like it wouldn't be the best thing to use.  And will the requery actually change the database at all?  I am looking to modify the database so there are no gaps in the Id's.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?  Anyway, it wouldn't be automatic, you'd have to do all the work in the program yourself, as well as turning off autoincrement for your primary key and handling that too.